# Vimeo API set privacy to disable

Tags: php, vimeo, privacy, vimeo-api

I'm using the new Vimeo API and I've successfully changed the title of a video but I also need to change the privacy settings. I thought I'd simply be able to do:

```
    $lib->request($uri, array('name' => $post_title, 'privacy' => 'disable'), 'PATCH');
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Helen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are a little out of date. The field should be "privacy.view"